# MySQL denies access only to laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, pdo

For some reason, MySQL won't connect for one specific webapp. It will connect from the CLI, Sequel Pro (like Mysql Workbench), even a webapp hosted in a sibling directory (`~/projects/iwork/`, `~/projects/idontwork`).

The only difference I can see is that the broken one is a laravel instance.

My `.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=idontwork_db
DB_USERNAME=dev
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

The error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dev'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `instances` limit 1)
```

My `config/database.php` (this is unchanged from laravel's default):

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

The dump of `config('database.connections.mysql')` as requested:

```
array:11 [▼
  "driver" => "mysql"
  "host" => "localhost"
  "port" => "3306"
  "database" => "idontwork_db"
  "username" => "dev"
  "password" => "nottherightpassword"
  "charset" => "utf8"
  "collation" => "utf8_unicode_ci"
  "prefix" => ""
  "strict" => false
  "engine" => null
]
```

The sibling webapp that works:

```
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_NAME = 'iwork_db';
$DB_USER = 'dev';
$DB_PASS = 'password';

$dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . $DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

So obviously one is trying to connect via Laravel and the other is native PDO, but I can't see any reason this should make a difference.

Things I've done:

- Composer and NPM have both installed their packages.
- I tried `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`.
- I've ensured the credentials are valid (like I said, I can get to `idontwork_db` from the CLI and Sequel Pro)
- Everything I've found on google seems to think I'm running out of connections, but this does not appear to be the case.

At this point I legitimately have no idea what is broken or how to troubleshoot it. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the output of `config('database.connections.mysql')` to your question?

Comment: @ceejayoz - Done. This seems to have highlighted the issue is that its getting the wrong password. Now I need to figure out why. Thank you, I didn't know that command was a thing.

Comment: try running this- php artisan config:clear

Comment: or change the variable DB_PASSWORD to something different

Comment: I found the problem, it turned out nginx was interfering. If anyone knows why and posts that as an answer (along with instructions on how to either fix it or tell php to ignore it), I'll accept it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to come from nginx and Laravel sharing ENV variables for some reason. In the working webapp, I was using a PHP variable to hold the information. In the Laravel webapp, I'm using the `.env`. For various reasons not applicable here, I had a line in my nginx file that said:

```
fastcgi_param   DB_PASSWORD           nottherightpassword;
```

Which is exactly what the `.env` file named the variable.

I'm not sure why the nginx param took precedence, but it did. All I had to do was change the var name (or make it use the password I wanted) and it started working.

So if mysql can connect everyone but through the webapp/site, be sure to check your web server and make sure you are not conflicting with anything there.

Comment: so my earlier comment did indeed help you :P

Comment: It did, yes. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, ENV vars from the webserver will take precedence - if they exist, it's much faster to use them than to look for a `.env` file. It's a performance thing. Glad we could point you in the right direction. :)